# why specific object can not be killed in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I'm making a game that the ship firing bullet to kill the enemy, in the game the enemy should disappear when the bullet hit them and the ship should disappear when it hit the enemy. When I'm testing the code, the enemy did disappear when the bullet hit them, however, the ship didn't disappear when it hit the enemy. Since these two action using the same logic, I don't  understand why one is working but the other is not. Here is my code:

```
# Make a ship.
ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
# Make a group to store bullets
bullets = Group()
# Make the enemy
enemys = Group() 

all_sprites = Group()
all_sprites.add(ship)

# Start the main loop for the game.
while True:
    check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets, enemys)
    ship.update()
    #enemys.update()
    # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared. 
    gf.update_bullets(bullets)
    gf.update_enemys(enemys)

    gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets, enemys)

    mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if 20 + 50 > mouse_position[0] > 20 and 20 + 20 > mouse_position[1] > 20:
                play_music = not play_music
                if play_music:
                    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                else:
                    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(ai_settings, screen, event, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
            gf.generate_enemy(ai_settings, screen, enemys, all_sprites)

    for any_enemy in enemys:
        if ship.rect.colliderect(any_enemy):
            ship.kill()
        for any_bullet in bullets:
            if any_bullet.rect.colliderect(any_enemy):
                any_enemy.kill()
                any_bullet.kill()
                ship.kill()
```

Comment: We can't debug the program properly if you only show us code fragments. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The `kill` function does not magically erase a `Sprite` from the screen.

It just removes the `Sprite` from all its groups.

So make sure that you actually use a `Group` to draw your ship sprite.

---

You didn't show all relevant code, but since you call a function called `update_screen` and pass `screen` and `ship` to it, I'll make the educated guess that you blit the ship "manually" to the screen instead of using a `Group` for drawing it.

---

You already have a `Group` called `all_sprites`, so drawing all sprites to the screen should be as simple as calling `all_sprites.draw(screen)`. Just make sure to add all sprites to this `Group`.